# Calling a method in another process from DLL which is loaded by a process

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, callback

Requirement:
A method in the Client application should be called when there is key press in the “On Screen Keyboard”

[image]

To get the above requirement done, we are creating a DLL and exporting a callback method.

```
extern "C"
{
   void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall onKeyPress(void);
}
```

This DLL will be loaded dynamically by the “On Screen Keyboard” and will call the callback method exported from the DLL.

```
Where I am stuck:
```

I have to call a method in the “Client application” from this exported callback function which is there in the DLL so that whenever there is a key press on keyboard, “Client Application” will get the notification.

I am unable to call the method in the client application.

Think that the On Screen Keyboard will load the DLL and will call the exported method as shown
[Sample code]

```
#pragma comment(lib,"..\\Debug\\SharedDll.lib")
__declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall calledByOnKeyPress(int scanCode);
int main(void)
{
    char ch = getchar();
    calledByOnKeyPress(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

from the DLL, i am trying to call a method in the application something like this.

```
void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall calledByOnKeyPress(int scanCode)
{
    callBackFunction(scanCode);
}
```

I am not getting how to go ahead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solution involves the following.

1. SharedDll should define a common data segment that can be shared among multiple processes.
2. Create a separate (message) thread in the Client Application to receive keyboard messages. Then set the Thread ID of this thread to the common data segment of SharedDll by the means of an exported function.
3. Your On Screen Keyboard process loads the SharedDll and calls the onKeyPress() function as usual.
4. Inside the onKeyPress() function in the SharedDll, it should check for a valid thread id which is stored in the common dll data segment. If there is a valid thread id then simply post a thread message.

The 4th step above will deliver your keyboard message from the "On Screen Keyboard" process to the Thread running inside the second process "Client Application"!

Usage of Dll common-data-segment is the decisive technique here.

**Inside the Client Application**

```
DWORD WINAPI KeyboardMsgThread( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    // Start the message thread

    MSG stMsg;
    while( GetMessage( &stMsg, 0, KEYBOARD_MSG_MIN, KEYBOARD_MSG_MAX ))
    {
        // Process the keyboard message here!
    }
    return TRUE;
}


bool CreateKeyboardMsgThread()
{
    DWORD dwThreadID = 0;
    CreateThread( 0, 0, KeyboardMsgThread, 0, 0, &dwThreadID );
    Sleep( 100 );// Let the message queue be created.
    SetKeyboardThread( dwThreadID );//Set the thread id to the common data area.
    return true;
}
```

**Inside the SharedDll**

```
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
DWORD Dll_dwThreadID = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.SHARED,RWS")
extern "C"
{
   void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall onKeyPress(void)
   {
       if( 0 != Dll_dwThreadID )
       {
           //When there is a valid thread id, simply post it to the thread. 
           //This thread can be inside any other process.
           PostThreadMessage( Dll_dwThreadID, KEYBOARD_MSG_MIN, 0, 0 );
       }
   }

   // Client Application will create the thread and calls this function to
   // set the thread-id to the common-data segment so that it can be 
   // utilized by the instance of SharedDll which resides in the process 
   // space of On Screen Keyboard.
   void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SetKeyboardThread(DWORD dwThreadID)
   {
       Dll_dwThreadID = dwThreadID;
   }
}
```

**Inside the On Screen Keyboard Application**

```
bool RecieveKeyboardNotification()
{
        onKeyPress();
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

When you load a .dll it will have different instances on different processes (so to speak).

For example, if App1 uses myDll.dll and App2 also uses myDll.dll , if you make a call inside myDll.dll from App1 , App2 won't be able to see it .

Dlls are just providers of compiled code at runtime.

For intra-process comunication you need to use intra-process approaches, such as communicating through sockets , shared memory ,etc .

In your case, where from my understanding the keyboard is on a different process, you need to signal through a socket (for example) to the client App the keyboard change.

Answer (score 0):

I asume, the client app loads the dll, and the dll shall call a function in the app.

So your app must register a function which should be called by the dll.
Therefore you need something like a  (simplified):

```
void registerCallback(CallbackFunctionPointer callbackfunction){
  //the app, or anyone else can call this to register a function which should be called 
  remember = callbackfunction;
}
```

and, if the the key is pressed, you call:

```
void something(char ch){
  //call the previously registered callback
  remember(ch);
}
```

the variable "remember" should be defined as static var, and must be declared, like:

```
typedef void (*CallbackFunctionPointer)      (char ch);
static CallbackFunctionPointer remember;
```

hope, this helps

Comment: I tried this before posting. This is not working. The reason might be, the calling code is in different process (On screen keyboard + Dll) and called code is in different process (Client Application).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood your question really. You want to communicate between 2 applications. If you don't want to use MNS' MichaelCMS' solution you can try semaphores. I recommend sockets.